# How to return a char function in C prog?

Tags: c

I am not sure how to store the return char function so I can return it to be used in the main function,

```
char process_3 (int step_2)
{
  if (step_2 % 2 == 0)
  {
    printf ("A");
  }
  else if (step_2 % 3 == 0)
  {
    printf ("F");
  }
  if (step_2 % 5 == 0)
  {
    printf ("K");
  }
  else if (step_2 % 7 == 0)
  {
    printf ("P");
  }
  if (step_2 % 11 == 0 || step_2 % 13 == 0)
  {
    printf ("T");
  }
  else
  {
    printf ("Z");
  }
  return process_3;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Return a char or return a function that returns a char or something else?

Comment: this is function that will return a char to the main function i suppose

Comment: Your question isn't clear. A "char function" would be a function that returns a char (a `char (*)(...)`). It's perfectly possible to return a pointer to a function from a function, but somehow I doubt that's what you want. Are you asking about how to return a value? If so, are you asking about returning a `char`, a string (in C, a `char *`) or something else? In any case, is there something about the [`return`](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/1.6.html#return) statement you don't understand?

Comment: ...  Type incorrectness aside (`process_3` is declared to return a `char` but actually returns a `char (*)(int)`, which is a pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns a `char`), what do you expect your code sample to do, compared to what it actually does?

Comment: Well this function is supposed to return a character like "A" to the main function so it can use with other stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
char process_3 (int step_2)
{
    char c;
    if (step_2 % 2 == 0)
    {
        c = 'A';
    }
    else if (step_2 % 3 == 0)
    {
        c = 'F';
    }
    if (step_2 % 5 == 0)
    {
        c = 'K';
    }
    else if (step_2 % 7 == 0)
    {
        c = 'P';
    }
    if (step_2 % 11 == 0 || step_2 % 13 == 0)
    {
        c = 'T';
    }
    else
    {
        c = 'Z';
    }
    return c;
}
```

You can assign chars to a variable using single quotes and return them from functions as well.

Answer (score 1):

A character literal in C is enclosed in single quotation marks, like this:

```
'a'
```

To return a character from your function you'd write a return statement with the character literal. For example:

```
if (step_2 % 2 == 0)
    return 'A';
```

This is very basic C stuff. I suggest Googling some tutorials and/or getting a book on C to learn the basics of the language.